# Mass user creation and connection in Guacamole RDP

Tags: networking, apache2, xfce, xrdp, rdp

So I'm using Guacamole with Google cloud to create remote desktop environments for people to use.
So how Guacamole works right now is:

1. Create user in Ubuntu
2. Crete user in Guacamole
3. Create Connection to the ubuntu account in Guacamole
4. Connect their Guacamole account and connection.

I have tried and tested this for a couple of users and its working fabulously. Just one problem, I have to create a huge amount of users in Ubuntu. And doing all these steps would take toooo much time. So is there any way to automate this?
Some way to like reduce the creation of separate Guacamole account and connection but rather one that sort of connects to the user account in Ubuntu?

Also if it helps, I'm using XFCE for environment and xrdp for RDP connections.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've already found a solution for this, but in case anyone else finds this question:

1. To my knowledge you cannot use the host OS to handle authentication.

   Unless you have a very specific use case you can just let Guacamole handle the authentication (using Database Authentication).

   But if you absolutely have to have backing Linux accounts then you
   can add these with the "adduser" command and some bash scripting:

   - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/adduser.8.html
   - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting
2. Guacamole doesn't have (to my knowledge) a command line for you to
   use, but it has a (largely undocumented) REST API that you can use to
   generate Guacamole Users, Connections etc.

   I have an ongoing project to wrap it (although it's for Powershell, sorry) @
   https://github.com/Adicitus/ps-guacamole-api.

   Check the the readme.md for sources and the "source" folder for examples, e.g:

   - Create a new User: https://github.com/Adicitus/ps-guacamole-api/blob/master/source/Users/New-GuacamoleAPIUser.ps1
   - Create a new RDP Connection: https://github.com/Adicitus/ps-guacamole-api/blob/master/source/Connections/New-GuacamoleAPIRDPConnection.ps1
   - Assign permissions to a connection: https://github.com/Adicitus/ps-guacamole-api/blob/master/source/Users/Set-GuacamoleAPIUserPermissions.ps1

   If you need to call the rest api from Linux, you can use the "curl" command:
   https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl

   Tutorial available here:
   https://www.baeldung.com/curl-rest
3. See point 1.
4. See repository from point 2.

   You need to give the user(s) at least READ permission on the connection(s).

Hope this helps someone :)